# Mysql select from two tables only unique rows by id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sql query/

```
select1 ... return =>1,2,3
select2 ... return =>4,5,3
```

I need return unique values from first select as (1 and 2).
Thank you.

Comment: Use not in and look up how to write sub queries it should help you

Comment: BTW it is *much* better to include DDL and your queries that you are using. (and welcome to SO :) )

Comment: Use the [DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) keyword, as doing subqueries is a non-trivial performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

Without a bit of DDL that's challenging* but you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT id, other_columns FROM `table1 name` as t1
WHERE t1.id NOT IN (SELECT id from `table2 name`)
```

*by challenging I don't mean challenging to write but challenging to make it work with least edits on your end.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `first sql query` as sub Query into `second sql query`

```
select * from .... where id Not IN ( select id from ... )
```